Div additions to Bootstrap formatting is messing up my layout
My code had an image positioned on the right hand side before I separated each H1 into separate  See picture of page before edit
But now that iv seperated into divs the picture sits on the top left of the screen.
See new page with revised code
Note the titles have changed from construction items to sports teams and I have added small pictures.
I am also using Bootstrap 4
ORIGINAL CODE
<section  class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="HeadingGroup" class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div id="headingGroup" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">
                <h1 class="skills">CONSTRUCTION<SPAN></SPAN></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">DEVELOPMENT APPLICATIONS<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">CLIENT SIDE PROJECT MANAGERS<span><span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">COST CONSULTANTS<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">_________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">QUANTITY SURVEYORS<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">_________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">DESIGN MANAGERS<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">_________________________<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">ARCHITECTS<span></span></h1>
                <h1 class="skills">_________________________<span></span></h1>
            </div>
        </div class="order-2 fixed-top col-lg-6 justify-content-right ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 justify-content-right">
            <img id="Brandpic" class="img-fluid " src="imgs/drafting2.jpeg" alt="Architects drawing and equipment">
        </div>
    </div>

NEW CODE
<section class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="HeadingGroup" class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div id="headingGroup" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">
                <!-- Start of Celtic Section -->
                <div id="celtic">  
                    <h1 class="skills">CELTIC <img id="celticBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/celticBadge.png" alt="Celtic Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Celtic Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Dortmund Section -->
                <div id="Dortmund">  
                    <h1 class="skills">BORRUSSIA DORTMUND <img id="dortmundBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/dortmundBadge.png" alt="Dortmund Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Dortmund Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Arsenal Section -->
                <div id="Arsenal">  
                    <h1 class="skills">ARSENAL <img id="arsenalBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/arsenalBadge.png" alt="Arsenal Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Arsenal Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Man Utd Section -->
                <div id="Manutd">  
                    <h1 class="skills">MANCHESTER UTD <img id="manutdBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/manutdBadge.png" alt="ManUtd Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Man Utd Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Braves Section -->
                <div id="Braves">  
                    <h1 class="skills">ATLANTA BRAVES <img id="bravesBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/bravesBadge.png" alt="Braves Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Braves Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Packers Section -->
                <div id="Packers">  
                    <h1 class="skills">GREEN BAY PACKERS <img id="packersBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/packersBadge.png" alt="Packers Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Packers Section -->
                
                <!-- Start of Knicks Section -->
                <div id="Knicks">  
                    <h1 class="skills">NEW YORK KNICKS <img id="knicksBadge" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/knicksBadge.png" alt="New York Knicks Badge that's on the shirts"><span></span></h1>
                    <h1 class="skills">________________________<span></span></h1>
                </div> 
                <!-- End of Knicks Section -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-2 fixed-top col-lg-6 justify-content-right">
        <div class="col-lg-6 justify-content-right">
               <img id="Brandpic" class="img-fluid" src="imgs/fanvestia.jpeg" alt="Architects drawing and equipment">
          
        </div>
    </div>
   
    

</section>


Please add more details with specific code so we can try to help. Right now its not clear what you have tried and want to achieve.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

There is nothing called justify-content-right. You should use justify-content-end instead of justify-content-right.

Instead of "justify-content-right" it should be "justify-content-end" when using Bootstrap 4. You also probably want to put the div containing the image is inside the HeadingGroup div. This is what I did and was able to get it looking pretty close to your original page:
<section class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div id="HeadingGroup" class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="headingGroup" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">      
        <!-- Start of Team Sections -->
        .
        .
        .
        <!-- End of Team Sections -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 justify-content-end align-self-end">
      <img id="Brandpic" class="img-fluid" src="<Image Link>" alt="Architects drawing and equipment" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

